# Keyboard buttons mixed up

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I just bought my new MSI laptop and shortly after i instaled windows 7 ultimate i found out that my keyboard is crazy. All buttons are mixed but in a very unique fashion that i cant relate to anything.

If i push all the buttons from 1 to backspace like 1234567890-= i will get 976P4 and button 7 is a scroll lock button and button 6 i guess is tab cause its highliting "file" in the notepad. Spacebar acts like a backspace and backspace acts like a 3 on a numberic keypad. How do i know that? it normally types 3 but if i press numlock on "screen on keyboard" it starts to act like PgDn.

The whole thing was also present in BIOS and in windows instalation but i ignored it thinking that it would go away after instaling windows. Now i cant even boot my laptop from a disc as if laptop didnt respond to me pushing f8.

Comment: Sounds like a defective keyboard.

Comment: If its happening in BIOS, its definitely a hardware issue

Comment: Try to reset your BIOS options, or even disabling the keyboards, and re-enabling it. If that doesn't work, it could be the keyboard itself. Try with an external keyboard if possible. And if the problem still persists, it could be the bios. If that is the case, then you need to flash the BIOS (but that's not the case I think). Anyway, try to give us updates for anything you try...

Comment: If you don't know how to reset your bios to default settings, here is a link: http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS

Comment: i was also on the same track as you and as i type this message im going with the laptop somehwere to try anything with external keyboard

Comment: You can also try looking at the keyboard language settings. I've seen it mix up some keys before, but not like this.

Answer (score 0):

If it were just in windows, I'd check keyboard settings, maybe it was set to a dvorak keyboard or something different.

But if bios is all mixed up too... does sound like bad hardware. It may be time to return / exchange the laptop since it's still brand new.